# How do I fix an "offset line of pixels" / image tearing in photo when using WebCamTexture?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When using the WebCamTexture's `WebCamTexture.GetPixels()` method to get a photo from the camera, occasionally there is an "image tear" that creates a "offset line" through the image.

I would say I see this ~5% of the time. I notice it more when there is motion happening, but I have also noticed it with still shots occasionally.

## **Does anyone know how to fix this?**

(I am deploying this to Android and iOS, so using the VR Photo Capture library or the Windows Photo Capture libraries will not solve my issue)

Some mitigations I have taken already (which seems a bit overkill) are below, but this still doesn't solve the image tear. My initial thought was that the webcam was trying to render over itself while I was getting the pixels, so I paused the webcam to test that theory, but that still didn't do the job.

The first image below is what I would expect all the time and the second image has the image tear described above.

```cs
// pause the webcam texture
MyWebCamTexture.Pause();
// wait until we can see that it is no longer playing
yield return new WaitUntil(CameraIsntPlaying());
// wait for the fixed update for good measure
yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
// wait until end of frame
yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
// get the pixels
var pix = MyWebCamTexture.GetPixels();
// set the pixels to the texture
textureRef.SetPixels(pix);
// apply
textureRef.Apply();
```

Good Picture:
[image: Good Picture]

Bad Picture:
[image: Bad Picture]